# How do you save the text in the terminal to various text formats?

Tags: terminal, tesseract

I'm playing around a bit with OCR software, in particular I'm spending a bit of time with tesseract. I got it to where I can load an image and get tesseract to rip the text from the image, in Linux terminal. I'm now trying to figure out how I can automatically save that ripped text to pdf, odf, txt and word formats, from the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `man 1 tesseract`, it seems you can make it save its output in one or more specific formats using a command in the form:

```bsh
tesseract image_file output_file pdf txt
```

where the four arguments play the role of `FILE`, `OUTPUTBASE` and `CONFIGFILE` (repeated twice), respectively, in the general command synopsis. This command creates two files, `output_file.pdf` and `output_file.txt`.